# basic C# hex editor performance issue

Tags: c#, string, performance

im having an issue with the speed of a simple hex editor i was working on
im using a background worker, simple for/foreach loop and couple simple statements but it's still way way slower than modern hex editors

that's the main loop that is taking too long to finish

```
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Count() - 1; i++)
    {
        string hex = Convert.ToString(buffer[i], 16);
        hexstring += ((hex.Length == 1 ? hex = "0" + hex : hex = hex)) + " ";
        double x = ((double)i/(double)buffer.Count());
        bw.ReportProgress((int)(x * 100));
    }
```

i know this could be written a million times better but im so curious what's causing this delay
a 1 mb exe. would take 5 mins of +50% cpu usage and this is far from being accepted, any thoughts ?

edit 1 : buffer is only a byte[], here is it's other only usage

```
buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(((string[]) e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, false))[0]);
```

Comment: a) Use StringBuilder. b) Don't call `ReportProgress` too much.

Comment: You don't need to call `bw.ReportProgress` for every byte (unless your data is less than 100 bytes :) )

Comment: True, consider `if (i % (buffer.Count / 100) == 0) bw.ReportProgress...` which will report each whole percent (will be true ~100 times depending on how divisible `buffer.Count` is by 100)

Comment: "Why string concatenation in a loop is slow" addressed in many existing questions on SO already. Nice (+1) answers here additionally address other issues with your code. I'd suggest when posting new question to minimize sample code to most essential part. I.e. in this case you should split string related code and notification related code into 2 separate samples and ask 2 questions if needed (could have helped you to find existing duplicates yourself).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hate to be "that guy" in this case, but you're reinventing a built-in wheel. There is a function in .NET which enables converting a byte array to a hex string. All you need is <strike>love</strike>, err this:

```
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(buffer);
```

I suppose this doesn't answer your question of why your solution is slow. Your solution is primarily slow because of string *immutability*. Strings are immutable (read-only) and when you concatenate them (AKA combine them with `+` or `+=` operators) you create a new object. You're creating 3, sometimes 4 strings per loop, which is not cheap since they take up memory and the garbage collector has to eventually collect them. You can avoid this by using a `StringBuilder` which floats a buffer under the hood when appending strings (vs creating new ones). Also, if the `buffer` is large, it's going to take a while - sort of the nature of the beast (more operations take longer). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

The reason is your use of the `+=` operator to concatenate strings.

Each time you do that, it will copy all the previous content of the string and the added content into a new string. Each time there will be more and more data to move. At the end of the loop it will move 6 MB of data each iteration.

When you are done with creating the string for the 1 MB of data, you will have copied 3 TB of data. That is a little more than there is available RAM, so a whole bunch of garbage collections also had to be done to clean up old strings and make room for new ones.

If you use a `StringBuilder` instead, you will see a dramatic change in performance.

---

Next thing to improve would be to report the progress a little less often. You could for example do that for every kilobyte processed instead of every byte.

Comment: Not just that but the `"0" + hex` concatenation as well.

Comment: @DaveHaney: That is very cheap in comparison as that is only an O(n) operation.

Comment: Doubles up on the string creations for 9 of 16 hex digits, does it not?

Comment: @DaveHaney: Yes, but it's only very short strings. At the end of the loop the code will copy 6 MB of data each iteration, so another little string is negligible compared to that.